# Will the Earth ever stop rotating?

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws, astrophysics, earth, planets

Will the Earth ever stop rotating or will it rotate for the entire lifetime of the universe (assuming that the Sun didn't exist, so the Earth would survive to the Red Giant phase)?

Answer (score 2):

Angular momentum is conserved, so the Earth will never stop rotating.

If you allow the Moon to exist but not the Sun, the tides raised on the Earth by the Moon will eventually slow the Earth so that it rotates once a month.

If you eliminate the Moon and allow the Sun to exist but never expand into a red giant, the Earth will eventually slow down to rotate on its axis once a year. This is because of the tides raised On the Earth by the Sun.

If you don’t allow the Sun or the Moon or the planets to exist, then the tides raised on the Earth by the nearby stars will eventually slow it down until *after an infinite time* it is non-rotating relative to the nearer stars. You may have to wait a while for this because the tides raised on the Earth by (say) Altair are about $10^{18}$ times less powerful in slowing the Earth down than the lunar or solar tides.

Comment: So even without moon and sun, the Earth would stop rotating by the tidal forces of surrounding stars? @MartinKochanski